# How to add ondragstart="drag(event)" to a dynamically created elements (img div)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Examples:

Image created dynamically:

```
var newImg = document.createElement('img');
newImg.setAttribute('id', newimage);
```

How do you give this image the property "   ondragstart="drag(event)"   "?

Thanks.

Comment: addEventListener....

Comment: addEventListener doesn't add "ondragstart" to the actual image, for example the image should have <img id=newimage ondragstart="drag(event)">.

Answer (score 1):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add the event

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener)
```

so your code would be

```
var newImg = document.createElement('img');
newImg.setAttribute('id', newimage);
newImage.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
```

The event will be passed.

Comment: So whats happening is when I drag and drop it into a div, the dragstart doesn't stay, so i can't drag and drop it into another div again. I want to add the attribute to the image itself so it stays permanently.

Comment: I just added the event listener again everytime the image is dropped into another div. (so at the end of the drop function).